# Sending Bulk emails in Laravel

Tags: laravel, mailing

How can I achieve sending bulk emails in laravel

Here below is my current code for achieving this but am getting Http error 504 because there is 10K user.

```
public function sendNewsletter(){

    $applicants = User::applicant()
                    ->whereMailSubscription(true)
                    ->get();

    $newsletter = NewsLetter::query()->where('id',$this->id)->first();
    $subject = $newsletter->subject;
    $message = $newsletter->message;

    foreach($applicants as $applicant){
        Mail::to($applicant)->queue(new NewsLetters($applicant,$subject,$message));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I would recommend to use something like Mailchimp to send newsletters.

Comment: No this was just example but I have other mass mailing activities in my application @Ruub

Comment: You could put your code above in a job so you won't have to wait for it to queue all of the mails.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external transactional email service like Sendgrid which is already integrated in Laravel out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#creating-jobs) to queue your mails. That way you won't have to wait for all your mails to be queued.

In this case your could generate a job class using, for example, `php artisan make:job SendNewsletter` and then paste your code from the function above into the `handle` function in the new job class. Then in your `sendNewsletter` function you could simply queue a new instance of the job class, e.g. `SendNewsletter::dispatch()`.

I would also suggest ["chunking"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#chunking-results) your results from the `users` table since you would be fetching so many results.